# Where should neutrals be bonded with a main panel and two sub-panels?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, grounding

I added a recording studio to my home. The electrician brought main feed with master breaker into new studio breaker box. The existing home breaker box was made a sub-panel fed from the studio main breaker box without a master breaker. They then added a additional sub-panel in a new garage fed from the first sub-panel.

I see the neutral and ground are on different bus bars in the home sub-panel but are tied together in the garage sub-panel. Is this correct or should the ground and neutral be separated and put on different bus bars in the garage. Hard to believe a licensed electrician would make a mistake.

I have built a post frame building and will be having it wired soon. I assume they will come off the first sub-panel as they did for the first garage. Can I expect them to have the neutrals and ground separated in first sub-panel but tied together in new post frame building?

Answer (score 2):

The main panel should have the neutral and ground tied together. In all sub panels, the neutrals and grounds need to be separated, on different bus bars with the neutral bus bar insulated from the panel. Sub panels in the same building as the main panel don't require ground rod. Sub panels in detached buildings need two ground rods driven 6' apart.

Comment: A separate ground rod for each sub panel?

Comment: Are you sure it's not a separate _pair_ of grounding rods for each _building_? IANAE, but that's my understanding.

Comment: @FreeMan  Good catch.

Comment: If I have a main panel in my house and  add a sub panel to serve the second level or a addition at opposite end of house are you saying I must have a ground rod driven for these sub panels?

Comment: Sub panels in the same structure as the main panel don't require a ground rod.

Answer (score 1):

Ground is tied to neutral ONLY at the main panel where the electricity enters the home. Every sub-panel from there carries ground and neutral separately. Two hot wires, one neutral wire, and one ground wire is needed to feed a sub-panel so that neutral and ground can remain separate.

Every building (separate structure) needs two ground rods driven at least six feet deep and at least six feet apart to be connected to the ground bar.